# Get Variable From File

Tags: php

I have file and the format is:

```
Class=CLASSNAME;
Name=AssignmentName;Grade=Grade
```

I need to get the data from each variable. Here's my echo code for the vars:

```
<?php
$lines = preg_split('~\s*[\r\n]+\s*~', file_get_contents('prod.txt'));

foreach($lines as $i => $line) {
    $pairs = explode(';', $line);
    foreach($pairs as $pair) {
        list($column, $value) = explode('=', $pair, 2);
        $columns[$column] = true;
        $rows[$i][$column] = $value;
    }
}

$columns = array_keys($columns);


echo '<center><table><thead><tr>';

#foreach($columns as $column) {
#    echo '<th>'.$column.'</th>';
#}

echo '</tr></thead><tbody>';

foreach($rows as $row) {
    echo '<tr>';
    foreach($columns as $column) {
        echo '<td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$row[$column].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</tbody></table></center>';

?>
```

Comment: You can split by ; and then each by =

Comment: That's a classic key/value pair format. Even `strtr`+`parse_str` would do.

Comment: Could you please attach output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an update for anyone looking on the internet for this, Mario helped me fix my problem.

> That's a classic key/value pair format. Even strtr+parse_str would do. – mario Aug 22 at 3:07

Thank you for your time and brain power